# Проставление рейтинга WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Всем привет!
Подскажите пожалуйста, есть задача, чтобы пользователь на сайте ставил оценку прошедшему уроку. Уроков от 10 до 30. Каждый урок - отдельный div. Плагины которые я пробовал - они при проставлении оценки, ставят эту оценку всем урокам.
Подскажите в какую сторону смотреть/копать/пробовать.
Буду благодарен за любую помощь, т.к. 4 дня гугления не помогли.

Comment: div - это html разметка. Ей нельзя никакой рейтинг поставить. Рейтинг можно поставить только какой-то сущности - записи, станице, комменту и тд

Comment: т.е. есть смысл переделать все уроки под запись?

Comment: Каждый урок - своя запись (или свой тип контента).

Comment: понял, спасибо большое